# gatsby-plugin-sitemap not excluding nested folders

Tags: gatsby, sitemap

I created the `excludes` array for gatsby-plugin-sitemap in my gatsby-config.js file; however, if there are nested folders, they aren't excluded. (FYI, I did a **clean** and then a **build** followed by a **serve** every time).

Here is my example:

```js
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-sitemap',
      options: {
        output: '/',
        excludes: [
          `/404/`,
          `/thanks`,
          `/screens/*`,
          `/screens/resources/*`,
        ],
      },
    },
```

If in the **/screens/resources/** folder, there is only a file, it works. If, however, there is another folder, like **/screens/resources/sections/**, those pages will appear in the sitemap.

Am I doing something incorrectly? Is there a way to exclude everything in the **/screens/** folder? I tried `/screens/*` and `/screens*` but nothing works if there are nested folders in the **screens** folder.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you might be able to give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss the only workaround which may work:

```
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-sitemap',
  options: {
    output: '/',
    excludes: [
      `/404/`,
      `/thanks`,
      `/screens/**`,
    ],
  },
},
```

It seems that the plugin works with a `minimatch` but it's not documented.